# Apache Storm, tweet processing topology

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have two spouts
Spout-1: Continuously emits tweets
Spout-2: Emits a new random number every 30 seconds.

Goal: I'm trying to filter the tweets based on the random from spout two.

I created a bolt that gets data from two spouts

```
builder.setBolt("process", new ProcessBolt())
        .shuffleGrouping("spout1")
        .shuffleGrouping("spout2");
```

But the "process" bolt seems to get data only from spout2. ie Random number spout.

What is the best way to achieve this? Should the topology be different.

P.S: The Random number generator has to be separate spout.

Comment: Your topology looks ok. You "process" bolt should get data from both spouts. No clue, why you do not get any data from "spout1". Are you sure, it does emit data?

Comment: I get data from spout1 if that is the only spout "process" bolt is listening to.

Comment: Weird. Can you maybe share your code of `ProcessBolt`? Did you start Web UI to check reported input record counts for "process" bolt? Did you check logs (nimbus, supervisor, workers) for errors?